# PHP Slim get current route group

Tags: php, rest, routes, slim

I want to get current route group.
For example `group1` from

```
$app->group('/group1', function () use ($app) {
    $app->get("/a"...
    $app->get("/b"...
    $app->get("/c"...
...
```

I can get **route pattern** from current route.
 The question is - **is there any special way to get current route group?**

Answer (score 0):

What about `$this` ? The code is taken [from their website.](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html)

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->group('/users/{id:[0-9]+}', function () {
    $this->map(['GET', 'DELETE', 'PATCH', 'PUT'], '', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        // Find, delete, patch or replace user identified by $args['id']
    })->setName('user');
    $this->get('/reset-password', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        // Reset the password for user identified by $args['id']
    })->setName('user-password-reset');
});
```